# NoSuchElement error even element is present Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I have to click on a Yes button in an overlay window, but it says NOSuchElement error but with inspect window when I am searching it with the same XPath it is displaying.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45CI6.png)

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Y']"));

I tried everything like Action.MoveToElement, Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable), ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript but nothing is working.

I  am afraid that maybe this is a popup related to payment so maybe it is not possible to click it using selenium but I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried finding `By.Id("Y")`?

Comment: Seeing as it is in an overlay, maybe it is in an `iframe`? I can't tell without seeing the full HTML